# Creating an observable 'completed' event in RxJS

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

Given: [the reactive extensions drag and drop example](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-Examples/blob/master/dragndrop/dragndrop.js) , how would you subscribe to just a drop event?

I have modified the code to subscribe to a 'completed' callback, but it does not complete.

```
    (function (global) {

    function main () {
        var dragTarget = document.getElementById('dragTarget');
        var $dragTarget = $(dragTarget);

        // Get the three major events
        var mouseup  = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');
        var mousemove = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document,    'mousemove');
        var mousedown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(dragTarget, 'mousedown');

        var mousedrag = mousedown
            .filter(function(md){                   
                //console.log(md.offsetX + ", " + md.offsetY);
                return  md.offsetX <= 100
                        ||
                        md.offsetY <= 100;
            })
            .flatMap(function (md) {

                // calculate offsets when mouse down
                var startX = md.offsetX, startY = md.offsetY;

                // Calculate delta with mousemove until mouseup
                return mousemove.map(function (mm) {
                    mm.preventDefault();

                    return {
                        left: mm.clientX - startX,
                        top: mm.clientY - startY
                    };
                }).takeUntil(mouseup);
            });


        // Update position
        var subscription = mousedrag.subscribe(
        function (pos) {                    
            dragTarget.style.top = pos.top + 'px';
            dragTarget.style.left = pos.left + 'px';
        },
        function(errorToIgnore) {},
        function() {    alert('drop');});

    }

    main();

}(window));
```

I have read that hot observables, such as those that have been created from mouse events, never 'complete'.  Is this correct?  How can I otherwise get a callback on 'drop'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
(function (global) {

    function main () {
        var dragTarget = document.getElementById('dragTarget');

        // Get the three major events
        var mouseup = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');
        var mousemove = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
        var mousedown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(dragTarget, 'mousedown');

        var drop = mousedown
                .selectMany(
                    Rx.Observable
                        .concat(
                            [
                                mousemove.take(1).ignoreElements(),
                                mouseup.take(1)
                            ]
                        )
                );
    }

    main();

}(window));
```

Edit:

If you think of an observable as an asynchronous function which yields multiple values, and then possibly completes or errors, you'll immediately recognize that there can only be one completion event.

When you start composing multiple function, the outer-most function still only completes once, even if that function contains multiple functions inside of it. So even though the total number of "completions" is 3, the outer-most function still only completes once.

Basically, that means if the outer-most function is suppose to return a value each time a drag completes, you need a way of actually doing that. You need to translate the drag completion into an "onNext" event for the outer-most observable.

ANY which way you can do that is going to get you what you want. Maybe that's the only kind of events that the outer-most function returns, or maybe it also returns drag starts and moves, but so long as it returns the drag completions, you'll end up with what you need (even if you have to filter it later).

The example I've given above is just one way to return the drag drops in the outer-most observable.

Comment: Well, that works.  Many thanks.  Now I just need to figure out why!  I wish there was a more elegant solution to force the observable to "complete" on .takeUntil(mouseup);

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! 

What has tripped me up so much is how important the order of composition is.  

Is it fair to say that with most functional programming, order is not important?  I think, coming from a fairly naïve linq background, I expected Rx to have the same 'order independence' as SQL.  

If anyone has any links to sources that talk about this, I would be grateful!

Comment: Order is *absolutely* important in SQL. What happens if you reverse the queries of a left join? You either get a lot more or a lot less results. In a lot of cases in SQL, you're simply filtering. Queries like that can be independent (unless you sort by and limit). There are certain things that are, and certain things that are not order-independant (order-by and join are just two examples). LINQ to Entities has no exception to this rule, nor does Rx. :) That being said, I'm sure there are things which Rx can express and SQL cannot.

Comment: Thanks, and of course you are right about SQL joins. That being said, can you expand on the function of **mousemove.take(1).ignoreElements()** in your answer above?

Comment: The SQL query analogy doesn't work quite as well when describing something such as that. Instead, try to think of an Observable as an asynchronous function with multiple return values. A function can be invoked (subscribe), yield a value (onNext), throw an exception (onError) and complete (onCompleted).

Comment: `take` is obvious, since we just stop listening after we get a single item. `ignoreElements` on the other hand, doesn't just `take(0)`, instead, it lets the observable complete, and then it itself completest, but it does not return any values. So, `mousemove.take(1).ignoreElements()` is an observable which will complete and only complete after a single mouse move.

Answer (score 3):

OP's link to the official example was down, it's here:

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/examples/dragndrop/dragndrop.js

There are two solutions to the original question, using either the primitive mouse events expanding upon the official example, or the native HTML5 drag and drop events.

### Composing from 'mouseup', 'mousedown' and 'mousemove'

First we use `mousedown1.switchMapTo(mousemove.takeUntil(mouseup).take(1))` to get the 'drag start' stream. `switchMapTo` ([see doc](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMapTo)) uses a combination of flattening (mapping 'mousedown1' to each of the first emit of 'mouse moving until mouse up', aka 'dragging') and `switch` ([see doc](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switch)), giving us the latest `mousedown1` emit followed by dragging, i.e. not just any time you click your mouse on the box.

Another 'mousedown' stream `mousedown2` is used to compose a `mousedrag` stream so we can constantly render the box while dragging.  `mousedown1`  above is prioritised over `mousedown2`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35964479/232288 for more information.

Once we have our 'drag start' stream we can get the 'drag stop' stream via: `mousedragstart.mergeMapTo(mouseup.take(1))`. `mergeMapTo` ([see doc](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMapTo)) maps 'mousedragstart' to each of the first emit of 'mouseup', giving us the latest 'mousedragstart' followed by 'mouseup', which is essentially 'drag stop'.

The demo below works with RxJS v5:

```js
const { fromEvent } = Rx.Observable;
const target = document.querySelector('.box');
const events = document.querySelector('#events');

const mouseup = fromEvent(target, 'mouseup');
const mousemove = fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');
const [mousedown1, mousedown2] = prioritisingClone(fromEvent(target, 'mousedown'));

const mousedrag = mousedown2.mergeMap((e) => {

  const startX = e.clientX + window.scrollX;
  const startY = e.clientY + window.scrollY;
  const startLeft = parseInt(e.target.style.left, 10) || 0;
  const startTop = parseInt(e.target.style.top, 10) || 0;

  return mousemove.map((e2) => {
    e2.preventDefault();

    return {
      left: startLeft + e2.clientX - startX,
      top: startTop + e2.clientY - startY
    };
  }).takeUntil(mouseup);
});

// map the latest mouse down emit to the first mouse drag emit, i.e. emits after pressing down and
// then dragging.
const mousedragstart = mousedown1.switchMapTo(mousemove.takeUntil(mouseup).take(1));

// map the mouse drag start stream to first emit of a mouse up stream, i.e. emits after dragging and
// then releasing mouse button.
const mousedragstop = mousedragstart.mergeMapTo(mouseup.take(1));

mousedrag.subscribe((pos) => {
  target.style.top = pos.top + 'px';
  target.style.left = pos.left + 'px';
});

mousedragstart.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('Dragging started');
  events.innerText = 'Dragging started';
});

mousedragstop.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('Dragging stopped');
  events.innerText = 'Dragging stopped';
});

function prioritisingClone(stream$) {
  const first = new Rx.Subject();
  const second = stream$.do(x => first.next(x)).share();

  return [
    Rx.Observable.using(
      () => second.subscribe(() => {}),
      () => first
    ),
    second,
  ];
}
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: seagreen;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.3/Rx.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>

<h3 id="events"></h3>
```

### Composing from HTML5 native 'dragstart', 'dragover' and 'drop'

The native events make things a little easier. Just make sure the dragover observer calls `e.preventDefault()` so the body element can become a valid drop zone. [See more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations#drop).

We use `switchMap` ([see doc](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap)) in a similar fashion as how `switchMapTo` is used above: flatten and map the latest 'dragstart' to the latest 'drop' to get our 'drag then drop' stream.

The difference is only when the user drops the div do we update the position.

```js
const { fromEvent } = Rx.Observable;
const target = document.querySelector('.box');
const events = document.querySelector('#events');

const dragstart = fromEvent(target, 'dragstart');
const dragover = fromEvent(document.body, 'dragover');
const drop = fromEvent(document.body, 'drop');

const dragthendrop = dragstart.switchMap((e) => {
  const startX = e.clientX + window.scrollX;
  const startY = e.clientY + window.scrollY;
  const startLeft = parseInt(e.target.style.left, 10) || 0;
  const startTop = parseInt(e.target.style.top, 10) || 0;
  // set dataTransfer for Firefox
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', null);
  console.log('Dragging started');
  events.innerText = 'Dragging started';

  return drop
    .take(1)
    .map((e2) => {
      return {
        left: startLeft + e2.clientX - startX,
        top: startTop + e2.clientY - startY
      };
    });
});

dragover.subscribe((e) => {
  // make it accepting drop events
  e.preventDefault();
});

dragthendrop.subscribe((pos) => {
  target.style.top = `${pos.top}px`;
  target.style.left = `${pos.left}px`;
  console.log('Dragging stopped');
  events.innerText = 'Dragging stopped';
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: seagreen;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.3/Rx.js"></script>
<div class="box" draggable="true"></div>

<h3 id="events"></h3>
```