# RxJs: Drag and Drop example : add mousedragstart

Tags: javascript, system.reactive, rxjs

How to implement a `mousedragstart` Observable using the [Drag and Drop RxJs's example](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/examples/dragndrop/dragndrop.js).

`mousedragstart` should be emit before the first `mousedrag` after a `mousedown` until the `mouseup`.

I think we have to play with `flatMap`/`take(1)`/`takeUntil(mouseup)` but I fail every time..

---

UPDATE

Difficulty here is not avoid `mousedrag` to be emitted before `mousedragstart`

Comment: sth like `mousedrag = mousedown.flatMap(_ => mousemove).first().repeat()` ? Should not be very far from that I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on my previous, not-addressing-the-root-problem answer, and the information you've provided, we conceptually have things defined as follows:

```
var dragTarget = document.getElementById('dragTarget');

var mouseup   = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document,   'mouseup');
var mousemove = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document,   'mousemove');
var mousedown = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(dragTarget, 'mousedown');

var dragstart = mousedown.flatMap(() =>
  mousemove
   .where(x => x.movementX !== 0 || x.movementY !== 0)
   .takeUntil(mouseup)
   .take(1)
);

var dragmove = mousedown.flatMap(() =>
  mousemove
    .where(x => x.movementX !== 0 || x.movementY !== 0)
    .takeUntil(mouseup)
);
```

The problem here is the overlap between the events; in terms of relationship to the underlying events, dragstart is triggered by EXACTLY the same thing as the first dragmove. In this case, order of subscription will determine order of execution, which, as you've said, isn't something you want to rely on. To address this, we must take control of the underlying events.

Here's a simple function that takes an observable and returns an array containing two observables which will be issued the same values as the original observable but in which the events will always be passed to the first observable before the second observable, regardless of which is subscribed to first:

```
function prioritize(s$) {
  var first = new Rx.Subject();
  var second = s$.do(x => first.onNext(x)).share();

  return [
    Rx.Observable.using(
      () => second.subscribe(() => {}),
      () => first
    ),
    second
  ];
}
```

From there, we can replace the appropriate parts above with something like this:

```
var mousedowns = prioritize(mousedown);

var dragstart = mousedowns[0].flatMap(() =>
 mousemove
   .where(x => x.movementX !== 0 || x.movementY !== 0)
   .takeUntil(mouseup)
   .take(1)
);

var dragmove = mousedowns[1].flatMap(() =>
  mousemove
    .where(x => x.movementX !== 0 || x.movementY !== 0)
    .takeUntil(mouseup)
);

dragmove.subscribe(() => console.log('dragmove'));
dragstart.subscribe(() => console.log('dragstart'));
```

Here's the whole thing working:

https://jsbin.com/qodilerofe/edit?js,console,output

Comment: It's quiet more complex to understand but it works fine! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

It should be something as simple as

```
var mousedragstart = mousedown.flatMap(() => mousemove.takeUntil(mouseup).take(1));
```

But it isn't. Chrome raises a mousemove event immediately after mousedown, which will cause the above logic to incorrectly yield an element before the user actually starts dragging. So you actually need something like:

```
var mousedragstart = mousedown.flatMap(() =>
      mousemove
         .where(x => x.movementX !== 0 || x.movementY !== 0)
         .takeUntil(mouseup)
         .take(1)
);
```

Comment: It does not work dragmove is emitted before dragstart.

Comment: What is it that you're calling "dragmove"? I've taken a look at the sample you've linked and re-read your question and I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Could you post some sample code that exhibits the problem?

Comment: [example code](https://plnkr.co/edit/4mR18RXWfZKTbILYlt1i?p=preview) I would like to get `dragstart` before any `dragmove`.

Comment: Ah. dragstart and dragmove are essentially composed of the same things (dragstart is really just the first dragmove, but you want it to occur immediately before the first dragmove). Because they both rely on the same underlying events, they're always going to trigger together. Which subscription runs first is determined by which subscription is taken first; all you need to do fix your problem is subscribe to dragstart before you subscribe to dragmove.

Comment: Yes I saw that.. but imagine if I'm making a library, I can't tell people to respect an order when they are subscribing event :) I think that it should exist a solution to emit this `dragstart` before `dragmove` (maybe something like `startWith`, but I don't get it works too..). If it's not possible.. I will achieve it without RxJs.

Comment: @MattBurnell why didn't you implement an unsubscribe method in your original (and neither here)?

Comment: @Ced Could you please elaborate on what unsubscriptions you expect to see? Here, mousedragstart is an observable, and in my other answer prioritize uses "using" to manage unsubscription from the only manually-taken subscription used in the solution (other than the test subscriptions taken to demonstrate use).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution for drag and drop:

```
let dragDiv = document.getElementById('drag');
let mouseisdown = false;
let startPos;

Observable.fromEvent(dragDiv, "mousedown").subscribe((e) => {
    mouseisdown = true;
    startPos = { x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY}
});
Observable.fromEvent(document, "mouseup").subscribe(e => mouseisdown = false); 


Observable
    .fromEvent(document, "mousemove")
    .filter(e => mouseisdown)
    .map((e) => {
        return   {
          left: e.clientX - startPos.x,
          top: e.clientY - startPos.y
        }
    })
    .subscribe( p => {
    dragDiv.style.top = p.top + "px";
    dragDiv.style.left = p.left + "px";
});
```

The **typescript** version:

```
let dragDiv = document.getElementById('drag');
let mouseisdown = false;
let startPos;

Observable.fromEvent(dragDiv, "mousedown").subscribe((e:MouseEvent) => {
    mouseisdown = true;
    startPos = { x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY}
});
Observable.fromEvent(document, "mouseup").subscribe(e => mouseisdown = false); 


Observable
    .fromEvent(document, "mousemove")
    .filter(e => mouseisdown)
    .map((e:MouseEvent) => {
        return   {
          left: e.clientX - startPos.x,
          top: e.clientY - startPos.y
        }
    })
    .subscribe( p => {
    dragDiv.style.top = p.top + "px";
    dragDiv.style.left = p.left + "px";
});
```