# RxJS: Advanced Drag and Drop - Prevent subscription in operator

Tags: drag-and-drop, rxjs, rxjs5

I try to implement drag and drop in RxJS. I have a DOM node with id `draggable` that can be dragged around. By using the standard procedure drag and drop works as expected.

But I tried to enhance drag and drop and this is where things get complicated. I attempt to change the background color of the element once dragging starts and change it back once it's dropped.

In my approach I'm using `switchMap` to map the results of the mouse move event into my observable which is triggered by the mouse down event. But since I use the mouse up event to complete the `switchMap`ed observable (`mm$` in the example below) I have no chance to get notified about the completion event of the inner observable except when I'm subscribing to it within the `switchMap` operator.

I know that subscribing within an operator is far from good practice and might lead to memory leaks. But what else can I do? How can this be done better?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/djwfyxs5/

```js
const target = document.getElementById('draggable');
const mouseup$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');
const mousedown$ = Observable.fromEvent(target, 'mousedown');
const mousemove$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');

const move$ = mousedown$
  .switchMap(md => {
    md.target.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    const {offsetX: startX, offsetY: startY} = md;
    const mm$ = mousemove$
      .map(mm => {
        mm.preventDefault();
        return {
          left: mm.clientX - startX,
          top: mm.clientY - startY
        };
      })
      .takeUntil(mouseup$);

    // Can the next line be avoided? 
    mm$.subscribe(null, null, () => {
      md.target.style.backgroundColor = 'purple';
    });

    return mm$;
  });

move$.subscribe((pos) => {
    target.style.top = pos.top + 'px';
    target.style.left = pos.left + 'px';
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered a similar question here: [RxJs: Drag and Drop example : add mousedragstart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950593/rxjs-drag-and-drop-example-add-mousedragstart/35964479#35964479)

It should be reasonably straightforward to adapt the answer to your purpose, as the streams still contain the events which expose the elements for which they were raised.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea. I figured out how to solve my problem with your draft in the other post. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b11gaewt/
Thanks for the reply. I'll mark your answer as the solution but suggest all interested readers to also have a look into my own solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39397186/434227

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled further with the problem to find a solution. In my attempt I use a helper observable that combines `mousedown` and `mouseup` events. By combining them with the `combineLatest` operator the latest value of the mousedown event can be accessed which contains the item that have been clicked (target).

This allows me to set the color correctly without the subscription in a temporary observable as seen in the issue. My solution can be accessed [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bq8s4dbt/).

I'm not sure if this can be done better/with less code using the same idea. I would be happy to see an improved implementation if possible.

Full code:

```js
const targets = document.getElementsByClassName('draggable');
const arrTargets = Array.prototype.slice.call(targets);

const mouseup$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');
const mousedown$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(targets, 'mousedown');
const mousemove$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');

// md      -------x------------------------------------------
// mm      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
// mu      -----------------------------------------x--------
// move$   -------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx---------
// s$      -------x---------------------------------x--------

const s$ = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
    mousedown$,
  mouseup$.startWith(null), // start immediately
    (md, mu) => {
    const { target } = md; // Target is always the one of mousedown event.
    let type = md.type;
    // Set type to event type of the newer event.
    if (mu && (mu.timeStamp > md.timeStamp)) {
        type = mu.type;
    }
    return { target, type };
    }
);

const move$ = mousedown$
  .switchMap(md => {
    const { offsetX: startX, offsetY: startY } = md;
    const mm$ = mousemove$
      .map(mm => {
        mm.preventDefault();
        return { 
          left: mm.clientX - startX,
          top: mm.clientY - startY,
          event: mm
        };
      })
      .takeUntil(mouseup$);
    return mm$;
  });

Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
    s$, move$.startWith(null), 
  (event, move) => {
    let newMove = move || {};
    // In case we have different targets for the `event` and
    // the `move.event` variables, the user switched the
    // items OR the user moved the mouse too fast so that the
    // event target is the document. 
    // In case the user switched to another element we want 
    // to ensure, that the initial position of the currently 
    // selected element is used.
    if (move && move.event.target !== event.target && arrTargets.indexOf(move.event.target) > -1) {
        const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        newMove = {
        top: rect.top, // + document.body.scrollTop,
            left: rect.left // + document.body.scrollLeft
      };
    }
    return { event, move: newMove }
  }
)
  .subscribe(action => {
    const { event, move } = action;
    if (event.type === 'mouseup') {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'purple';
      event.target.classList.remove('drag');
    } else {
        event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      event.target.classList.add('drag');
    }
    event.target.style.top = move.top + 'px';
    event.target.style.left = move.left + 'px';
  });
```