# Flag first and last events during mouse drag using rxjs

Tags: rxjs

I'm a newbie with rxjs but I want to create a drag and drop handler with it and I have the following function:

```js
  function createDraggable$(element) {
    const mouseDown$ = fromEvent(element, 'mousedown');
    const mouseMove$ = fromEvent(window, 'mousemove');
    const mouseUp$ = fromEvent(window, 'mouseup');
    return mouseDown$.pipe(
      switchMap((start) => {
        const {
          offsetLeft: initialLeft,
          offsetTop: initialTop,
        } = element;
        return mouseMove$.pipe(
          map((move) => {
            const deltaX = move.pageX - start.pageX;
            const deltaY = move.pageY - start.pageY;
            return {
              isFirst: false,
              isLast: false,
              start,
              move,
              deltaX,
              deltaY,
              initialLeft,
              initialTop,
              left: initialLeft + deltaX,
              top: initialTop + deltaY,
            };
          }),
          takeUntil(mouseUp$),
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  createDraggable$(el).subscribe((drag) => {
    if (drag.isFirst) {
      dragstart.emit();
    } else if (drag.isLast) {
      dragend.emit();
    } else {
      drag.emit();
    }
    if (isHorizontal) {
      el.style.top = `${drag.top}px`;
    } else {
      el.style.left = `${drag.left}px`;
    }
  });
```

As you can see the `isFirst` and `isLast` values are constant, but I would like to change them to `true` accordingly. The first drag event is when the first mousemove fires and the last is the one when mouseup fires.

I've tried using `combineLatest` with two extra streams:

```js
const first$ = mouseMove$.pipe(first());
const last$ = mouseMove$.pipe(takeUntil(mouseUp$), last());
return combineLatest([first$, mouseMove$, last$]).pipe(
  switchMap(([_first, _move, _last]) => {
...
```

But to no avail, since `combineLatest` waits on last$ to produce at least one value, which it won't...

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950593/rxjs-drag-and-drop-example-add-mousedragstart/35964479 may be helpful. It's not exactly the same question, and it's against and older version of rxjs, but it covers some of the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clunky as it is this is my solution:

```js
  function createDraggable$(element) {
    const mouseDown$ = fromEvent(element, 'mousedown');
    const mouseMove$ = fromEvent(window, 'mousemove');
    const mouseUp$ = fromEvent(window, 'mouseup');
    return mouseDown$.pipe(
      switchMap((start) => {
        const {
          offsetLeft: initialLeft,
          offsetTop: initialTop,
        } = element;
        const drag$ = mouseMove$.pipe(takeUntil(mouseUp$));
        return combineLatest([
          merge(of(true), drag$.pipe(take(2), last(), switchMapTo(of(false)))),
          merge(of(false), drag$.pipe(last(), switchMapTo(of(true)))),
          drag$,
        ]).pipe(
          map(([isFirst, isLast, move]) => {
            const deltaX = move.pageX - start.pageX;
            const deltaY = move.pageY - start.pageY;
            return {
              isFirst,
              isLast,
              start,
              move,
              deltaX,
              deltaY,
              initialLeft,
              initialTop,
              left: initialLeft + deltaX,
              top: initialTop + deltaY,
            };
          }),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

It is not ideal, since the `isFirst` and `isLast` events double up:

```
1. isFirst: true, isLast: false, move.deltaX: -1
2. isFirst: false isLast: false, move.deltaX: -1 // deltaX is again -1
3. isFirst: false isLast: false, move.deltaX: -2
4. isFirst: false isLast: false, move.deltaX: -3
5. isFirst: false isLast: false, move.deltaX: -4
6. isFirst: false isLast: true, move.deltaX: -4 // deltaX is again -4
```

Ideally events 1 and 2 as well as 5 and 6 will be both combined, but I really don't know rxjs to properly do it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can enforce an emission on `$last` stream

```
mouseMove$.pipe(takeUntil(mouseUp$), last(),startWith(null))
```

and in `switchMap` you can try to handle the null case and do nothing by returning `empty`

```
switchMap(([_first, _move, _last]) => { if(!last) return empty() ...
```